# EventListener is working only when browser window is inactive (not on the top)

Tags: javascript, typescript, event-listener, two.js

I am using Two.js to draw svg image in Angular application.

after drawing the svg (which have some elements inside) in two.js, I add event listener to its elements like this:

```
this.courtRenderer.update(); //after this command two.js draw the svg

for (const trajectory of this.trajectories) {
  trajectory.renderedLine._renderer.elem.addEventListener('mouseenter', (event) => {
    this.onRenderedLineMouseEnter(event, this.trajectories.filter((selectedTrajectory) =>
    selectedTrajectory.renderedLine.id === trajectory.renderedLine.id));
  }, false);
  trajectory.renderedLine._renderer.elem.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    this.onRenderedLineMouseLeave(this.trajectories.filter((selectedTrajectory) =>
    selectedTrajectory.renderedLine.id === trajectory.renderedLine.id));
  }, false);
}
```

Then I have a handler for this which changing the line width and line color and also sending information to service to open a popup in mouse position.

```
    private onRenderedLineMouseEnter(event, trajectories){
    let renderedLine;
    for (const trajectory of trajectories){
      renderedLine = trajectory.renderedLine;
      renderedLine.linewidth = renderedLine.linewidth * this.appConfig.courtRenderer.highlightedTrajectoryWeight;
      renderedLine.stroke = this.appConfig.courtRenderer.colors.highlightedTrajectory;
    }
      this.courtRenderer.update();
      const popupPosition = new PopupPosition(renderedLine.id, event.layerX, event.layerY);
      this.virtualCourtService.selectShot(popupPosition);
    }
```

It is not working till I run console (F12) in the browser... I do not know why, but as I said when I click F12 on google chrome everything is working... Why not before?

Edit:
When I set a breakpoint in method onRenderedLineMouseEnter and I mouseenter on the line breakpoint is catched and then it is working without Inspector.

I have also added some console.log to this method and either with Inspector and without inspector the code is fired, but only with inspector (or with breakpoint) the UI changes are made.

Comment: Based on the inspector setting, browser cache is disabled when you open the inspector; probably your problem is because of the browser cache.

Comment: This situation is happening on each browsers (Brave, Chrome, Firefox, Edge) and even on other machines.

Comment: What hapens if you run the code after a timeout, could it be your code runs to soon?

Comment: the same. I set a timeout for 5seconds and it is working in the same way. 
Code is fire in correct time and the proof on this maybe that all logs are fired when I move mouse into the trajectory. The problem is that the UI is not refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed something else - when browser window is inactive handlers are working correct but when I click on the browser window and it is active, then it is not working.
That is why I wrote about inspector - this tool caused that inspector is active window and browser content is inactive.
[image]